# Where to store custom php scripts called via cron

Tags: php, debian, cron

I want to move my php scripts out of the /var/www so that they are not accessible via a URL. But where is the most logical place to store these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/var/phpscripts could fit for you. There is no default, but it's mandatory that stays outside the public folder.

Answer (score 2):

Any option might be good one, 
i for example like the /home/%user% path, it's outside the reach of the web (depends on where i've pointed apache to look). 
you can also keep it on /var/www but chmod it so no one can access it outside.

Answer (score 2):

I like `/usr/local/[something]`, ie `/usr/local/cron/` or `/usr/local/bin/` which is what $work rolls with. Other than that using the `$HOME` directory of the user the script will run as is a good place to put it. `$HOME/bin/` or `$HOME/cron/` are solid options.

The "most logical place" is really up to you.

Comment: +1 for `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @TomO'Connor if only there were a place for a **us** e **r** to put their **local** scripts and **bin** aries...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a bin directory under the $HOME directory of the user invoking the cron job. If you're invoking as the httpd user, you could still do that, but add an `.htaccess` file to the bin directory to prevent access via the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `/opt/$application/bin`, which is mostly inkeeping with FHS, but really my heart is with `/usr/local/bin`.